# Sitecore Edit Frame issue

Tags: experience-editor, presentation, mvc

I am having issues when passing Guid as the data source for edit Frame.

When I populate the Guid directly it works fine but while binding it from model am getting an error message

Code:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions
@{
    var itemid = @Model.PropertyGuid;
}

@foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item listItem in @Model.DiningServiceItem)
{
    using (Html.EditFrame("@itemid", "DininglEvents", null, null, null, null))
    {
        <li> @listItem.Name</li>
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
An error occurred. [Log message: Could not get item with id: from database:master]
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: From what I see, the problem is that you have quote marks around @itemid, am I right?

Comment: when i remove quotes am getting this error  Rendering Controller: Dining. Action: index: An unhandled exception occurred

Comment: check the GUID format

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs you can pass the datasource argument in one of the following formats:

- /sitecore/content/Home
- {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}
- RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem.ID.ToString()
- RenderingContext.Current.PageContext.Item.ID.ToString()
- Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.DataSource To use this format, you
- must create a Data Source field in a rendering (Presentation, Details, Controls, Your Rendering).

> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/using_editframes

What format is your @itemid guid in?

Perhaps try:

```
.ToString()
```

on your Item ID.

Comment: working code   using (Html.EditFrame(@itemid.ToString(), "DininglEvents", null, null, null, null))

Comment: Great. Just .ToString() was needed then?